# Match and capture every word from a list AND what's between these words

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to capture every words in a string that are inside an array, and I also want to capture every word that isn't (basically splitting the string by the words that I have and the one that I don't).

For clarification, here's an example:

**Input:**

> string myString = "ID-NUMthatissomeboringstuffNAME"
>
> string[] wordsList = new string[] { "ID", "NUM", "NAME" };

**Desired output captures (in order):**

> (ID)
>
> (-)
>
> (NUM)
>
> (thatissomeboringstuff)
>
> (NAME)

**My regex:**

```
string regex = String.Format("(({0})|.*)", String.Join("|", rules))
```

Of course it doesn't work, when I tried to replace, it would just give me the first letter caught.

Once more, my original problem is already solved (*I just wanted to parse a string like that and put some value depending on what I found in it... A mere `Replace` suffice :p*), but for the sake of completeness, I'd like to solve it this way anyway.

Comment: So you want to match the stuff in CAPS and the stuff inbetween the stuff in CAPS? What have you tried?

Comment: @MattBurland oh, forgot that yeah. I want to match it all, indeed.

Comment: @Closers Explain please. How can I clarify something I don't know is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it `({0}|[^({0})]+)`.  Here's the [Regexr breakdown](http://regexr.com/38spk).

**Code**

```
var input = "ID-NUMthatissomeboringstuffNAME";

string[] wordsList = new string[] { "ID", "NUM", "NAME" };
string regex = String.Format( "({0}|[^({0})]+)", String.Join( "|", wordsList ) );

foreach(var match in Regex.Matches( input, regex )
                          .OfType<Match>()
                          .Select( match => match.Captures[0].Value ) ){
    Console.WriteLine( match );
}
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, looks good to me :p

Answer (score 0):

```
indexOf(string)
```

gives you the position of the string and the you can use

```
substring(indexStart, word length)
```

to get it

Comment: I think he meant using Regex. As he said, a simple replace would get the job done

Comment: That's it, but thanks for the input anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is more readable, but you could use this regex:

`@"(?<g0>[A-Z]*)(?<g1>[^A-Z]*)(?<g2>[A-Z]*)(?<g3>[^A-Z]*)(?<g4>[A-Z]*)"`

It does what you find, finds groups of uppercase letters, then non-uppercase letters, etc, and stores them in named groups.

Comment: Well, I may have not been clear, the uppercase words are just examples here. They may not be uppercase'd in the end.